# SharePoint 2016 is running slow after migration from 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, 2016

Recently we have migrated from SharePont 2013 (standard) to SharePoint 2016 (standard) version. But, SharePoint intranet site running super slow.

Below are the configuration of New sharepoint environment:

**Application Server:**

```
RAM : 32 GB
HD: 800GB
Processor: 4 cores
OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
```

**Database Server**

```
RAM: 12 GB
HD: 800GB
processor: 2 Processor
OS : Windows Server 2012 R2
```

My **Content DB size is 100GB** and root site having **20+ subsites**, I tried almost everything to  boost performance but no luck. I followed the link:
https://www.networkworld.com/article/2210265/tech-primers/10-steps-to-optimize-sharepoint-performance.html

Can anyone suggest, do I need to do infrastructure changes or anything else?

Help appreciated. 
Thanks